# How does the following map function work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, transpose

```
>>>uneven = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['g','h','i']]
>>>map(None,*uneven)
```

O/P: [('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', None, 'i')]

The code above can be used for finding transpose of a matrix.
However iam unable to understand how it WORKS.

Comment: Do you understand what `map` do? And what `*` means?

Comment: yes, i do understand.The "None" got me a bit confused. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `*` operator, the list is broken up into position arguments for the map. This is what you're actually running:

`>>> map(None, ['a','b','c'], ['d','e'], ['g','h','i'])`

When you pass multiple iterables to `map`, then the function (in this case `None`) is applied to every iterable in parallel. It processes `'a', 'd', 'g'` first, and so on.

**Edit:**
As pointed out by Jon below, when you pass in `None` as the `map` function, it gets special cased to be the identity function, i.e. `lambda id: id`. This special casing of `None`'s use in `map` has been removed in Python 3.

Comment: One key point missing in this answer is that `None` as the callable is special cased to be `lambda id: id`... and that's now prohibited in Python 3.x

Comment: And other note - this is "better" written and more cross-version compatible using `list(izip_longest(*uneven))` (since 2to3/other tools will convert to `zip_longest` where needs anyway)

Answer (score 1):

```
map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list
```

from the documentation of [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

If more than one sequence is given, the
function is called with an argument list consisting of the corresponding
item of each sequence, substituting None for missing values when not all
sequences have the same length.

**If the function is None, return a list of the items of the sequence**

Using sequence with `*` operator `zip` it according to the position of items in sequence.